# Why is validation in array of mongoose schema not working?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have the following mongoose model:

```
const collaboratorDetailsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: {
        type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
        required: true
    },
    stacks: {
        type: Array,
        required: true,
        default: undefined,
        validate: {
            validator: function (v) {
                return v.length > 0;
            },
            message: "Atleast one stack must be provided",
        },
    },
    experienceLevel: {
        type: Number,
        min: 1,
        max: 5,
        required: true,
    },
    note: {
        type: String,
    },
});
```

Then I have defined another schema which contains `collaboratorDetailsSchema` as an array.

```
const collaboratorSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
    projectId: {
        type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
        ref: "Project",
        unique: true,
        required: true,
    },
    collaborators: [collaboratorDetailsSchema],
});
```

And finally, created the MongoDB model as follows:

```
const Collaborator= mongoose.model("Collaborator", collaboratorSchema, "Collaborators");
```

But when I push objects into the `collaborators` array using `findByIdAndUpdate` command with `$push`, the `required` validation and the custom validation as defined in the `collaboratorDetailsSchema` are not enforced.

Which means I'm able to store the following document:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5f07e8c91027230f2429a7b3"),
    "projectId": Objectid("5f07411154dd016500a8d585"),
    "collaborators": [
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("5f07e8c91027230f2429a7b4"),
            "stacks": [],
            "experienceLevel": 10,
            "note": "Sample Note"
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

This should have given an error because

- userId is not present (`required: true` specified in schema)
- stacks is an empty array (requires minimum 1 element)
- experienceLevel exceeds max value of 5

I'm using Postman for testing and `"mongoose": "^5.9.20"` and `"express": "^4.17.1"`